# How can I validate a model created with Entity Framework fluent API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a User model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

which is added to my data context via the fluent API:

```
public class UserMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(u => u.Id);
        builder.Property(u => u.FirstName).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(u => u.LastName).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

and I would like to be able to validate it outside the context of an action where I can simply check `ModelState.IsValid`, like this:

```
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
Validator.TryValidateObject(user, new ValidationContext(user), results, true);
```

Is there a way for Validator to use the rules from the `IEntityTypeConfiguration`? Thanks.

Comment: No, there's none. Why don't you use DataAnnotations?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I could, but I started this project using fluent API, so before I went back and changed all the models to use attributes, I thought I'd see if there's a way to hook them together. Thanks

Comment: Notice that it's preferred not to work with entities directly in web api/mvc but rather to use ViewModels/DTOs. Whether you prefer that or not is another topic though

Comment: @Andy you got any solution?

Comment: @UttamUghareja: no, I never got one. I think I switched to data annotations on this project.